# Advice on insert function for AVL tree - C++

Tags: c++

I also posted this to reddit but received no assistance. I have an AVL tree project and one of the functions I need to implement is an insert function which adds set of values in the tree. The output which I am getting is incorrect, I will show after the code. All of the code except the insert, delete, and levelOrder functions (delete and levelOrder are not asked about here) were provided by my professor so I believe it can be assumed everything is coded correctly.

My insert function

```
bool AVLTree::insert(string ss, string na){
    AVLNode* newPtr = new AVLNode(ss, na);
    updateHeight(newPtr);

    //Tree is empty, make the new Node the root of a new tree
    if(root == nullptr){
        root = newPtr;
        return true;
    }
    //Tree is not empty
    else{
        AVLNode* node = root;
        while(node != nullptr){
            //If the ssn is already in the tree
            if(node->ssn.compare(newPtr->ssn) == 0){
                return false;
            }
            else if(node->ssn.compare(newPtr->ssn) > 0){
                if(node->left == nullptr){
                    break;
                }
                node = node->left;
            }
            else{
                if(node->right == nullptr){
                    break;
                }
                node = node->right;
            }
        }

        if(newPtr->ssn.compare(node->ssn) < 0){
            node->left = newPtr;
        }
        else{
            node->right = newPtr;
        }
        updateHeight(node);
        balance(root);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then the two functions used in there balance() and updateHeight() were provided by the professor, here they are:

Balance()

```
AVLNode* AVLTree::balance(AVLNode* node){
    updateHeight(node);
    if (balanceFactor(node) == 2) {
        if (balanceFactor(node->left) < 0) {
            node->left = rotateLeft(node->left); // for left right case
        }

        AVLNode* temp = rotateRight(node);
        updateHeight(temp);
        return temp;
    }

    if (balanceFactor(node) == -2) {
        if (balanceFactor(node->right) > 0) {
            node->right = rotateRight(node->right);  // for right left case
        }
        AVLNode* temp2 = rotateLeft(node);
        updateHeight(temp2);
        return temp2;
    }
    return node;
}
```

updateHeight()

```
void AVLTree::updateHeight(AVLNode* node){
    int hl = height(node->left);
    int hr = height(node->right);
    node->height = (hl>hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AVLTree.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
  AVLTree temp;
  temp.insert("05", "a");
  temp.insert("08", "b");
  temp.insert("09", "c");
  temp.insert("03", "d");
  temp.insert("06", "d");
  temp.insert("07", "d");
  temp.insert("02", "d");

  temp.print();

 }
```

My current output is

```
      8
     / \
    5   9
   / \
  3   6
 /     \
2       7
```

When I believe I should be getting

```
        6
     /     \
    3       8
   / \     / \
  2   5   7   9
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I apologize if I didn't include enough information, just let me know if you need more.

Comment: it would be much more convenient if all the code was available. I think there is a problem with the way you call `updateHeight`. Shouldn't you call it for each node all the way up, not only for the new node's parent?

Comment: @user3188346 i apologize, the code for this project is pretty long and the last time I made a post with a lot of code I was told it was wrong to do that and then it got down voted and never answered, if you want to see another function let me know and I'll edit it in or something. Anyways the professor's comment says [code]updateHeight [/code] should be used whenever the tree is modified. So I think you are correct, where should I call it in my while loop though? I'm not too sure.

Comment: Those return values aren't there for casual usage. If a subtree root changes, the result of the `balance()` function will reflect that change (i.e a rebalance can change the root of a tree. You're currently ignoring that result, simply calling `balance(root);` Unrelated, you also have a blatant memory leak in your code, whereby duplicate values cause (a) an allocation of a new node, then (b) a quick-exit via `return` upon discovering the duplicate, orphaning the allocated node and its memory. In short, don't allocate until you reach where a node *should* be, but isn't.